# Laravel vue read message event

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, broadcast

I have chat, and I have code:

```
    watch: {
    message() {
        Echo.private('chat')
            .whisper('typing', {
                name: this.message
            });
    }
},
methods: {
    send(){
        if(this.message.length != 0 && this.message.length <= 4000) {
            this.chat.message.push(this.message);
            this.chat.user.push('you');
            this.chat.time.push(this.getTime());
            axios.post('/sendMessage', {
                message: this.message,
                //lastName: 'Flintstone'
              })
              .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                this.message = '';
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
        }
    },
    getTime() {
        let time = new Date();
        return time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes();
    }
},

mounted() {
    Echo.private('chat')
        .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
            this.chat.message.push(e.message);
            this.chat.user.push(e.user);
            this.chat.time.push(this.getTime());
            console.log(e);
        })
        .listenForWhisper('typing', (e) => {
            if(e.name != '')
                this.typing = 'typing..';
            else
                this.typing = null;
        });
}
```

How I can watch, if user read message? I send post request on my controller. Where I can call function `messageIsReaded`. But How I can Watch this event? I can watch 'typing', but how watch if message readed?

Comment: Vue is good but it cant yet read a users mind.. you would just have to presume its read'ed on any change to another model event like `typing`..